# Cannot retrieve jSON values in phonegap using jQuery

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsonp

I cannot display jSON data from a url in my browser using this script but I cannot find the source of the error.

The url (http://www.entertainmentcocktail.com/cp/index.php) contains what I understand is valid jSON data but there is nothing returned when I use this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var output = $('#output');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://www.entertainmentcocktail.com/cp/index.php',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                        timeout: 5000,
                        success: function(data, status){
                            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                                var name = '<h1>'+item.location+'</h1>'
                                + '<p>'+item.id+'</br>';

                                output.append(name);
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>
```

EDIT: The target page with the jSON data generates the information from a database with this code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "SERVER";
$username = "USER";
$password = "PASS";
$database = "DB";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT id, name, location FROM table_name ORDER BY id";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . json_encode($records);
?>
```

Comment: It looks the last `;` is breaking JSON parser. Try removing it. Also, not sure about the `()` around the entire json string is needed.

Comment: Do you mean the `;` before `</script>`? If so, I removed it and no luck - same result.

Comment: When I fetch the example URL, the last character is `;`. If you pass the content of that page as a JSON string, it will be invalid because of that last character.

Comment: Oh I see. How can that be avoided? The script to display the data is very simple - `$records = array();
 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $records[] = $row;
 }`

Comment: Try http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ -> Load JSON data (enter you URL)... Then click the 'Viewer' tab at to top. It gives invalid JSON variable error. Now remove the final semi colon and try again. It succeeds.

Comment: I see... how would I go about removing that last semicolon then? It's all automatically generated - I've edited my original post so you can see the full code being used but I don't see how to remove just the last character.

Comment: If you cannot modify what that server returns, you'll have to strip the problematic character on you side before attempting to parse it into a JSON object. (Use `substr()` to strip the last character.)

Comment: I have managed to take off the last `;` and also the `()` surrounding it ([see link](http://www.entertainmentcocktail.com/cp/index.php)) but it still isn't presenting anything on the page with the same code for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running this code from the same domain (www.entertainmentcocktail.com)? If not, you might be running into a XSRF issue.

What browser are you using to test? In Chrome you can right click and goto "Inspect Element" which then has a little red mark in the bottom right hand corner if there is a java script error. You should be able to find more information here.

http://cl.ly/image/261T3T360M34 - Screen shot of errors in bottom right hand corner.

How are you generating your json string? You should ideally use the built in PHP function: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Update:

From your comment, your issue is the ordering if your scripts. Change it to be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var output = $('#output');

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.entertainmentcocktail.com/cp/index.php',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: function(data, status){
                        $.each(data, function(i,item){
                            var name = '<h1>'+item.location+'</h1>'
                            + '<p>'+item.id+'</br>';

                            output.append(name);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: No, I'm running it locally, and yes there is an error - it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. The jSon string is indeed being generated via PHP.

Comment: Try moving your <script> to be after your inclusion of the jquery library, it's not finding jquery!

Comment: Are you still getting the error in your browser? if so, what line number is it pointing to.